# Customer custom attribute checkbox in backend magento 1.9

Tags: checkbox, magento-1.9

I added my customer attribute, and I want to display these fields as checkboxes in account information tab. I created checkbox in the frontend easily but the backend is not. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you have created this customer attribute but it seems that you didn't added the adminhtml_form. 
If you want to edit a new customer attribute from the admin you must add the proper forms when creating the attribute: **adminhtml_customer**

Take a look here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97018/adding-custom-customer-attribute-to-admin-panel/97023#97023

If the attribute is already created, you can edit this directly in DB in the table: **customer_form_attribute** and add adminhtml_customer to the attribute you created.

Regards

Comment: I mean I added the field in admin form, but it is type: text. And I want to change to the checkbox. Finally, I've done it by myself. But thanks for your reply.